# How to manage Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) wth Next.js and Heroku?

Tags: heroku, out-of-memory, next.js

I got this error:

```
heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

My Next.js package.json looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT"
  },
```

My `free` plan can use 512 MB of memory.

Found this in docs https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-memory-use

```
web: node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=920 server.js
```

But I do not know where to write. My package.json has a different format.

Comment: This statement goes in the `Procfile` in the root of your project. But for nextjs, you can simply use [vercel](https://vercel.com) if it meets your needs.

Comment: I like better Heroku. So what should I write into `Procfile`?

Comment: Just the *process types* go in the `Procfile`, in your case `web: node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=920 server.js` this is assuming the file to start your node server is `server.js`

Comment: Do you think 920 is the right value? We are allowed to use 512MB.

Comment: According to the docs this memory issue is mostly because of the garbage collector, although I'm not sure what 920 exactly represents here, since this is from the docs this should likely work

Comment: i have the same issue but no server.js file, i guess this is the gimmick to nextjs, can this error also be issued by a next/image sharp error ??? And if not what can i do about the missing server.js file ? Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue due to using `next/image` for images

Comment: I had the same issue, also using `next/image`. I saw a warning in the heroku logs 'sharp missing in production' advising to add the sharp package which nextjs will use for image processing if present. After adding the sharp package the memory warnings disappeared (as far as I can tell during a few hours of uptime).

Are you serving images from your nextjs app?